# How do I check if a process (Firefox) has quit?

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-12.04, tunnel, openssh, socks-proxy

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, with all updates installed.

I made a simple shell script that starts a SOCKS5 tunnel and launches Firefox (with correct network proxy settings) to use the tunnel. How do I recognize when Firefox has ended (when I close it) so that I can close the tunnel? Also, it would be awesome if I could run this in the background, but not necessary.

> #!/bin/sh
>   ssh -fCN -D 10000 server.com
>   firefox //To lauch firefox using Ubuntu
>   ? Code to determine when firefox has quit
>   Code that kills the tunnel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `trap` command to tell the terminal to kill the tunnel when it exits :

```
#!/bin/sh

# Create the tunnel
ssh -fCN -D 10000 server.com
pid=$!

# Tell the terminal to kill the tunnel on exit or error
trap "kill $pid" EXIT

# Launch Firefox
firefox
```

When you exit Firefox, the shell will exit and kill the tunnel.

Comment: Thanks! I had to change the pid=$! because using ssh with -f causes a fork, which the shell cannot see. Therefore, I changed the variable to capture it correctly.
`pid=$(echo \`ps ax | awk '/100000\ tunnel/{print $1}'\`)`

Comment: You mean `server.com` (instead of `tunnel`), right ?